# Python offline speech recognition?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Could anyone recommend a speech recognition library for python 3 which is completely offline and free? If so could you also add steps to installing this library. I have tried `pocketsphinx` but the live speech recognition is too inaccurate for what I would like.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Kaldi, it is not easy to install, but it is more accurate than pocketsphinx. For local decoding you can use something like

https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-server/

the model is here http://kaldi-asr.org/models/m1

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it another go installing on Ubuntu because at this point I can't get it to work on Mac OS. If I can install Kaldi then I'll try the websocket. Thank you, if it works I will mark as answered.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I installed Kaldi from here http://jrmeyer.github.io/asr/2016/01/26/Installing-Kaldi.html but the websocket can't find the directory `voice data` and won't build. So no idea anymore.

Comment: You have to edit the actual kaldi path in Makefile

Comment: OK thank you. I got past that error and then about five others but there is another one I'm stuck on. This is what I get...```D1Ev' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad valuecollect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```. I get it while running make for the web-socket.

Comment: You have to recompile Kaldi with --shared configure option

Comment: (1)
go to tools/  and follow INSTALL instructions there.
(2) 
go to src/ and follow INSTALL instructions there. These are the install instructions I followed for Kaldi. I went back into them and tried `make --shared` but neither worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Wow ok, I'm a bit silly. So I realised I needed to run `./configure --shared` then `make depend` and `make` in the src directory which worked. So then I went back to the web-socket and ran `make` in that. No errors but no change in files in the directory. So anyway I think it may be working and I will test it as soon as I can. Thank you

Comment: Now when I run `python3 test_local.py` I get this error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)
`. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to provide the file as an argument I presume. You also have to arrange the model files. The error must be printed above the segmentation fault.

Comment: Ok,I followed the install instructions for the model in kaldi which seemed to work but when running `test_local.py` it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAI's [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) (off-line, MIT license, Python 3.9, CLI) yields some highly accurate transcription. To use (tested on Ubuntu 20.04 x64 LTS):

```
conda create -y --name whisperpy39 python==3.9
conda activate whisperpy39
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg
whisper recording.wav
whisper recording.wav --model large
```

If using an Nvidia 3090 GPU, add the following after `conda activate whisperpy39`

```
pip install -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
conda install pytorch==1.10.1 torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch
```

---

Performance info below.

Model inference time:

| Size | Parameters | English-only model | Multilingual model | Required VRAM | Relative speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tiny | 39 M | `tiny.en` | `tiny` | ~1 GB | ~32x |
| base | 74 M | `base.en` | `base` | ~1 GB | ~16x |
| small | 244 M | `small.en` | `small` | ~2 GB | ~6x |
| medium | 769 M | `medium.en` | `medium` | ~5 GB | ~2x |
| large | 1550 M | N/A | `large` | ~10 GB | 1x |

WER on several corpus from https://cdn.openai.com/papers/whisper.pdf:

[image]

WER on several languages from https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/language-breakdown.svg:

[image]